# Move people search to list page

Tags: users, search

Is there a way or module that allows me to move the search tab of the People page to the List tab?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views makes the users and content page a lot friendlier. On of the things it does is putting a search field on the users page.

One of the modules I use on every project.